# Netbeans IDE problem on MacOSX

Tags: java, netbeans

I installed Netbeans IDE on Mac OS X few weeks ago. In the code-completion window while writing Java code, I always get the proper full list of possible code completions but in the window that pops-up which is supposed to display JDK documentation entry (all details) for each possible completion, it always say that JDK documentation was not found! It never happened to me when I worked on Windows.

I even downloaded and explicitly added JDK docs library to Netbeans library but to no use. Has anybody faced such problem? Please help! Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since nobody else answered and I had the same issue, but wasn't motivated enough to figure it out, I tracked down the way to do it... look [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/joshy/archive/2006/04/how_to_get_code.html).

The only changes I did was to use the latest JavaDoc instead of the 1.5 one and to use Java Platforms in step 3 (I am using Netbeans 6.5, I guess the menu structure changed from when he did it).